# Facebook "Send me an email" permission

Tags: facebook

I prompted for the "email" permission in my Facebook application. However, when I access the graph api of the user, there is no field called "email" available even though I know they have an email on Facebook. Why?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know based on my experience with their API, Facebook does not offer access to the messaging framework, therefore you are not allowed to send messages on a user's behalf.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ - "email - Provides access to the user's primary email address in the email property. Do not spam users. Your use of email must comply both with Facebook policies and with the CAN-SPAM Act."

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought you were referring to the new messaging system.

Could you be receiving the public information only because you aren't authenticated (OAuth) correctly?

Comment: I don't think so because I can see all the other extended permissions just fine. For example, user_birthday, etc.

Comment: My only guess would be that the permission hasn't been accepted by the user. Using the [test console](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console) might help you do interim testing as you grant the permission. The Graph API does make any results from the "email" permission available as well so I believe the permission is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a test user where you know they accepted the permissions prompt and have an email?

How are you trying to get the email?  I get them via FQL:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, email from user where uid = {userid}
```